# Alljoyn android Events and Actions sample not working

Tags: android-ndk, alljoyn

Trying to run Android sample 'Events and Actions' downloaded from https://allseenalliance.org/framework/download

Downloaded 'Core SDK - debug' which has sample eventaction and .apk in bin folder.

Installed it, but doesn't work. Is anyone able to run it?

**Edit**: Exception in the Logcat:

> 08-29 09:06:16.978 29314 29328 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.allseen.sample.eventaction, PID: 29314
>   08-29 09:06:16.978 29314 29328 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__exidx_end" referenced by "/data/app/org.allseen.sample.eventaction-1/lib/arm/libMyAllJoynCode.so"...

I have tried building the library **MyAllJoynCode.so** using Android ndk, but I couldn't able to build it. I get below exception

> root@jay-dev:~/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_core/samples/eventaction/Android# ndk-build
>   [arm64-v8a] Compile++      : MyAllJoynCode <= AndroidJNIBridge.cc
>   In file included from /root/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/atomic.h:30:0,
>                    from /root/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/ManagedObj.h:38,
>                    from /root/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/Message.h:30,
>                    from /root/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/AuthListener.h:32,
>                    from /root/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn/BusAttachment.h:34,
>                    from jni/event/AndroidJNIBridge.cc:19:
>   /root/alljoyn/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/inc/qcc/posix/atomic.h:30:25: fatal error: sys/atomics.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                            ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   /root/android-ndk-r12b/android-ndk-r12b/build/core/build-binary.mk:474: recipe for target 'obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/MyAllJoynCode/event/AndroidJNIBridge.o' failed
>   make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/MyAllJoynCode/event/AndroidJNIBridge.o] Error 1

Comment: Please share the problem you had during the installation of the apk. If the apk can be installed successfully but the app crashes, please post the logcat

Comment: Edited the question with more log information.

Comment: thanks. Which Alljoyn version are you using?

Comment: I tried on Alljoyn RB14.12 and also on master branch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were using Android NDK level 20 (or later).
The NDK's android-20 platform directory no longer contains the atomics.h file (they removed it), which caused the AllJoyn build failure you saw:

> dist/cpp/inc/qcc/posix/atomic.h:30:25: fatal error: sys/atomics.h: No such file or directory

Prior to AllJoyn release 16.10, a workaround is simply to copying the NDK's android-19 atomics.h file to its android-20 (or later) platform directory.

However, the AllJoyn-related issue has been fixed as of September 2016 (i.e. no longer dependent on atomics.h), and the fix is included in AllJoyn release 16.10.

More information is provided in JIRA https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE-3216